# What's the best way to prevent a Sitecore user from accidentally unpublishing the home page?

Tags: sitecore

In the last year we've had a couple of incidents where a user accidentally unpublished the 'Home' item (which is the root item in our site), before publishing it to our 'Live' database, which removed it from the site.

**What is the best way to prevent important content from being unpublished from a production Sitecore web site?**

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "unpublished"? Deleted? A workflow state? Or are you using a plugin which can unpublish items from the web DB?

Comment: The user went into the items Publish settings and deselected the Production database publish target, and/or deselected the Publishable checkbox.

Comment: Thanks for the accept, out of curiosity can you comment on which solution works best for you?

Comment: I've added a comment to your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your "easy" security options are to either protect the Home item itself from editing, or to restrict access to publishing options. Using standard Sitecore security, disable write access on Home for a particular user role, or disable read access on the Publishing Restrictions chunk or button in core (/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks/Publish Restrictions/Change).

If you really don't need anyone besides admins editing the Home item, you can also Protect the item from the Configure ribbon.

If you'd like to just disable publishing restrictions on Home, that could be more complicated.  Your best approach would likely be to extend the SetPublishing command. The following is untested:

1. Extend `Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.SetPublishing`
2. Override `Execute(CommandContext)`
3. Check `context.Items[0]` to see if it's your home page (GUID or Template ID check if multi-site). If so, abort. If not, call `base.Execute(context)`. (You could also add a check for `Sitecore.Context.User.IsAdministrator` if so desired.)
4. Replace `item:setpublishing` command in Commands.config.

Reference `Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.SetPublishing` in your favorite decompiler as needed.

Comment: I can't restrict access to the Home item or to publishing options via security, because this user (role) should have access to those. I had an idea that I would probably need to do something in code but wasn't really sure where to start (what command to override, etc): this points me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just mark the home item as protected. You can double-check but I believe that prevents any mod/del of an item. In the Configure tab, see Protect Item button